# Receive email notification when script ends

Tags: r, gmail

How easy is it to send e-mail through R?

using this

```
> library(sendmailR)
> 
> 
> from <- "myaddress@gmail.com"
> to <- "receiveraddress@gmail.com"
> subject <- "Performance Result"
> body <- "This is the result of the test:"                     
> mailControl=list(smtpServer="snmpt server address")
> 
> sendmail(from=from,to=to,subject=subject,msg=body,control=list(smtpServer="ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM"))
```

I receive this error:

```
Error in wait_for(code) : 
  SMTP Error: 5.5.2 Syntax error. jp9si1521863wjb.204 - gsmtp
```

I guess I should make something from the side of gmail but what should I have to make?

I tried also this for gmail using real address but I didn't receive any error but neither any e-mail

```
library(mailR)
sender <- "sender@gmail.com" # Replace with a valid address
recipients <- c("receiver1@gmail.com") # Replace with one or more valid addresses
email <- send.mail(from = sender,
to = recipients,
subject="Subject of the email",
body = "Body of the email",
smtp = list(host.name = "aspmx.l.google.com", port = 25),
authenticate = FALSE,
send = FALSE)
```

Comment: Also gmailr is appropriate but how can I make it to a server without need to login when the program ends. I tried this manually `library(gmailr);gmail_auth("compose");insert_message(mime(From="you@me.com", To="any@one.com",
Subject="hello", "how are you doing?"))`
but it is not helping

Comment: There are about a dozen other posts on StackOverflow on this topic that should answer all your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me with slightly different smtp settings (host name, port and ssl and addition of user.name and passwd) and also with 'authenticate' and 'send' changed to TRUE.

```
library(mailR)  
send.mail(from = sender,
        to = recipients,
        subject = "Subject of the email",
        body = "Body of the email",
        smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                    user.name = sender, 
                    passwd = "senders_password", ssl = TRUE),
        authenticate = TRUE,
        send = TRUE)
```